# compute accuracy of Band RNN

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

So I am trying to figure out how to compute the accuracy of a BandRNN.

BandRnn is a diagonalRNN model with a different number of connections per neuron. For example:
[image]
here C is the number of connections per neuron.

My current model training is as follows:

```
model = ModelLSTM(m, k).to(device)

model.train()

opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)

best_test = 1e7
best_validation = 1e7

for ep in range(1, args.epochs + 1):

init_time = datetime.now()
processed = 0
step = 1

for batch_idx, (batch_x, batch_y, len_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
    batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)

    opt.zero_grad()

    logits = model(batch_x)
   
    loss = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)

    acc = sum(logits == batch_y) * 1.0 / len(logits)
    print(acc)

    loss.backward()

    if args.clip > 0:
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), args.clip)

    opt.step()

    processed += len(batch_x)
    step += 1
    print("   batch_idx {}\tLoss: {:.2f} ".format(batch_idx, loss))

print("Epoch {}, LR {:.5f} \tLoss: {:.2f} ".format(ep, opt.param_groups[0]['lr'], loss))
```

And my model test is as follows:

```
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():

for batch_x, batch_y, len_batch in test_loader:
    batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)
    logits = model(batch_x)
    loss_test = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)
    
    acc = sum(logits == batch_y) * 1.0 / len(logits)
    

for batch_x, batch_y, len_batch in val_loader:
    batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)
    logits = model(batch_x)
    loss_val = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)

if loss_val < best_validation:
    best_validation = loss_val.item()
    best_test = loss_test.item()

print()
print("Val:  Loss: {:.2f}\tBest: {:.2f}".format(loss_val, best_validation))
print("Test: Loss: {:.2f}\tBest: {:.2f}".format(loss_test, best_test))
print()

model.train()
```

I am struggling with thinking about a way to compute the accuracy of this model and I would like to receive some suggestions about a way to do so.
Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the question is. Is your current code not calculating accuracy correctly or are you looking for suggestions for other metrics to measure model performance? In general, how you calculate accuracy or any other metric should not depend on the model's internal architecture, but only its output and your ground truth labels.

Comment: Hi, I currently do not have a clue about how to even compute the accuracy, If you can give me an example of how to do so it will be great.

Comment: I believe this line in your code is already attempting to calculate accuracy: `acc = sum(logits == batch_y) * 1.0 / len(logits)`. Though you probably want to argmax the logits before comparing with the labels.

Comment: Thank you! It could be great if you will post an answer will a full solution so I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this line in your code is already attempting to calculate accuracy:

```py
acc = sum(logits == batch_y) * 1.0 / len(logits)
```

Though you probably want to argmax the logits before comparing with the labels:

```py
preds = logits.argmax(dim=-1)
acc = sum(preds == batch_y) * 1.0 / len(logits)
```